# sbt about gives 0.13.15 while i have installed sbt 1.0.4

Tags: sbt

Hi new to sbt i have installed sbt form here `https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html` (windows sbt-1.0.4.msi) and then i do `sbt about` it yields

```
C:\Users\rajnish.kumar>sbt about
"C:\Users\rajnish.kumar\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.4"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\rajnish.kumar\project
[info] Set current project to rajnish-kumar (in build file:/C:/Users/rajnish.kumar/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.15
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/Users/rajnish.kumar/}rajnish-kumar 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.6
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.6
```

Question is why it is printing sbt version 0.13.15 instead of 1.0.4 ?. i am using windows 8.

hi tried the same thing on windows 10 and getting the expected result

```
C:\Users\rajnish>sbt about
"C:\Users\rajnish\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.4"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\rajnish\project
[info] Set current project to rajnish (in build file:/C:/Users/rajnish/)
[info] This is sbt 1.0.4
[info] The current project is {file:/C:/Users/rajnish/}rajnish 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.4
```

Comment: Did you get the answer, because I am facing same situation. I have installed sbt 1.0.0 version on my system and after setting PATH variable, command line output for command "sbt sbtVersion" gives me 0.13.15.

Comment: @  Shashi Shankar no , but as i moved to windows 10 there it was working

Answer (score 1):

In order to really enforce SBT version when building your project you should specify this version in the `project/build.properties` file. Here is the content of this file in my project:

```
sbt.version = 1.0.4
```

If I navigate to the root project folder and run `sbt about` it shows me

```
[info] This is sbt 1.0.4
[info] The current project is {file:/ssd2/projects/ADMP/}admp 1.0
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.9
```

If I change the version in the `build.properties` to

```
sbt.version = 1.0.1
```

and then run `sbt about` it shows me

```
[info] This is sbt 1.0.1
[info] The current project is {file:/ssd2/projects/ADMP/}admp 1.0
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.9
```

SBT knows ho to load particular version sources, loads them if current version of SBT is different, compiles that version of SBT and then builds your projec with that version of SBT.

Why it shows by default 0.13.15 for your case - I am not sure. Probably in your project you have that version specified in the `build.properties`, probably for some other reasons.

Try also check with help of `sbtVersion` task. Run the command `sbt sbtVersion`.

Comment: No i am not in any specific project i.e i am not running sbt about form any specific project location.What i am simply doing is installing sbt , then opening cmd prompt and running sbt about.

Comment: I've added one more way to check SBT version at the end of the answer. Check and let's see what it shows on your machine.

Comment: sbt is not supposed to be run just like that, outside of any project. The only valid use case for that is `sbt new ...` (and even it will litter in `./target/`).

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out be not so clean installation. Step I have done to fix this: 
1. Manually delete sbt installation directory from Program files.
2. Delete the directory c:\Users\.sbt
3. Uninstall sbt using add remove program. 
4. Install sbt new version. 
5. Cross check environment variables e.g.SBT_HOME and path 
6. Run sbt sbtVersion to verify new installed version.